# Content Security Policy cordova problems

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, content-security-policy

I made an app using ionic on my windows pc, now when switching to a mac i get this error from the console

> "Refused to load
>   https://lorem.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=59502592&cb=11&v=5
>   because it does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content
>   Security ".

Already i tried modifying my CSP tag in my header, i cant seem to get it to work tho. Also i tried re-adding all plugins/platforms/resouce.

The tag im using right now is

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: cdvfile: gap:; style-src 'self'  https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com https://lorem.firebaseio.com/*; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Also im wondering why i cant add this to my whitelist plugin like i did in the past

```
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.178.13:8100"/>
  <allow-intent href="*.firebaseio.com"/>
  <allow-intent href="auth.firebase.com"/>
```

----------------------------- edit -----------------------------

To fix all of my issues i used this 3 tags

```
content="default-src * data: cdvfile: gap:; 
      style-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline';
      img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
      script-src 'self' https://lorem.firebaseio.com/* 
                        https://cdn.firebase.com
                        https://*.firebaseio.com
                        'unsafe-eval'">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have added your url on style-src section, If you are trying to load a remote script source, you have to add your source url in the **script-src** section.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="default-src * data: cdvfile: gap:; 
      style-src 'self'  https://cdn.firebase.com
                        https://*.firebaseio.com
                        https://lorem.firebaseio.com/*;
      script-src 'self' https://lorem.firebaseio.com/* 'unsafe-eval'">
```